# Slide from left menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make menu which slides in a submenu from left, on hover action. But with this code makes all submenus open, not just the submenu from the hovered link.
This is my HTML code:

```
<ul id="NavMeni">
    <li><a href="/hr">Početna</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Top Level Link</a>
        <ul class="NavPodMeni">
            <div><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i><p class="clear"></p></div>
            <h1>Privlaka</h1>
            <li><a href="#">Second Level Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Second Level Link Level Link Level Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Second Level Link</a></li>
        </ul></li>
    <li><a href="/en">Nin</a>
        <ul class="NavPodMeni">
            <div><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i><p class="clear"></p></div>
            <h1>Privlaka</h1>
            <li><a href="#">Second Level Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Second Level Link Level Link Level Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Second Level Link</a></li>
        </ul></li>
    <li><a href="/de">Kalendar događanja</a></li>
    <li><a href="/it">Smještaj</a></li>
    <li><a href="/hr">Aktivni odmor</a></li>
    <li><a href="/en">Multimedija</a></li>
    <li><a href="/de">Info</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is my jQuery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("nav ul#NavMeni li a").hover(function () {
        $("nav ul#NavMeni li > .NavPodMeni").animate({ 'left': '250px' }, 'slow');
    });
    jQuery("nav ul#NavMeni ul.NavPodMeni p i").click(function () {
        $(".NavPodMeni").animate({ 'left': '0px' }, 'slow');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$(this)` to target hovered anchor and [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to get the first `.NavPodMeni` when traverse up the DOM tree from your `a` and `i` element:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("nav ul#NavMeni li a").hover(function () {
        $(this).closest('.NavPodMeni').animate({ 'left': '250px' }, 'slow');
    });
    jQuery("nav ul#NavMeni ul.NavPodMeni i").click(function () {
        $(this).closest('.NavPodMeni').animate({ 'left': '0px' }, 'slow');
    });
});
```

You also need to remove `p` inside your second selector since `i` is not the children of `p`

Comment: nothing happens with closets(), now nothing is opening.

Comment: @Akul Von Itram, with closets(), or with closest()?

Comment: I guess this wouldn't work, Since `.NavPodMeni` is not a parent to `a`. How about `$(this).parent().find('.NavPodMeni').animate({ 'left': '250px' }, 'slow');` ?